# Como listar o log de um repositório GIT local através do PHP?

Tags: php, git

O `git` tem um comando chamado `git log`, que mostra o histórico de commits do repositório.

Eu gostaria de saber se teria como usar esse `git log` do GIT e passá-lo para um `array` do PHP.

No caso, o script PHP estaria dentro do diretório do repositório.

A minha ideia era conseguir listar, através do PHP, o `git log` do branch atual pelo PHP.

Mais ou menos assim:

```
projeto
    .git/
    listar_log_git.php
```

**NOTA**: A ideia é fazer isso num repositório local, como no título da pergunta. Ou seja, eu quero listar esses dados a partir do repositório clonado, e não remotamente.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Basicamente o comando dentro do `PHP`

```
exec('git log', $result);
print_r($result);
```

resultado:

```
Array
(
    [0] => commit 693673def6d3cb8f196cf5988af70b87c4ff4cb3
    [1] => Author: None <none@none.com>
    [2] => Date:   Wed Nov 7 23:14:14 2018 -0200
    [3] => 
    [4] =>     Create README.md
    [5] => 
    [6] => commit f0a3ce8f990a693352b597e51ac2a874e07da2fa
    [7] => Author: None <none@none.com>
    [8] => Date:   Wed Nov 7 23:02:55 2018 -0200
    [9] => 
    [10] =>    Create index.php
)
```

agora é trabalhar a informação a sua maneira construindo um novo `array`, exemplo:

```
<?php

    exec('git log', $result);
    $new_result = array();
    $j = -1;
    for($i = 0; $i < count($result); $i++)
    {
        if (strpos($result[$i],'commit') !== false)
        {
            $new_result[++$j]['commit'] = substr($result[$i], strlen('commit'));
        }
        else if (strpos($result[$i],'Author:') !== false)
        {
            $new_result[$j]['author'] = substr($result[$i], strlen('Author:'));
        }
        else if (strpos($result[$i],'Date:') !== false)
        {
            $new_result[$j]['date'] = substr($result[$i], strlen('Date:'));
        }
        else if (!empty($result[$i]))
        {
            $new_result[$j]['message'] = trim($result[$i]);
        }
    }

    print_r($new_result);
```

resultado:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [commit] =>  693673def6d3cb8f196cf5988af70b87c4ff4cb3
            [author] =>  None <none@none.com>
            [date] =>    Wed Nov 7 23:14:14 2018 -0200
            [message] => Create README.md
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [commit] =>  f0a3ce8f990a693352b597e51ac2a874e07da2fa
            [author] =>  None <none@none.com>
            [date] =>    Wed Nov 7 23:02:55 2018 -0200
            [message] => Create index.php
        )

)
```

Answer (score -1):

Isso vai depender da empresa, pro exemplo o GitHub é: 
Os dados abaixo podem ser fornecidos no : https://github.com/settings/applications

```
   <?php  
    $user = 'flesheater'; $token = 'ced38b0e522a5c5e8ab10'; 
    $curl_url = 'https://api.github.com/users/' . $user . '/repos';
    $curl_token_auth = 'Authorization: token ' . $token;


     $ch = curl_init($curl_url);

     curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('User-Agent: Awesome-Octocat-App', $curl_token_auth));
      $output = curl_exec($ch);
      curl_close($ch);
      $output = json_decode($output);

      if (!empty($output)) {
        foreach ($output as $repo) {
          print '<a href="' . $repo->html_url . '">' . $repo->name . '</a><br />';
        }
      }
```

É só verificar a empresa e acessar a API dela.

Comment: Eu falei "repositório local", na pergunta. O script vai estar dentro da pasta que é um clone de um repostório. Até coloquei o arquivo `.git` no diretório.